# Pie plate cog on SRAM 2x

Tags: gears, compatibility, drivetrain, sram

Okay guys, I'm trying to re-find fitness in my mid-40s.

My bike has a SRAM Apex (don't laugh, if it's good enough for Alberto Contador, it's good enough for me - and you!) 10-speed drivetrain with 48/32 front and 11/32 in the rear.  My 275lb diabetic pampered lard ass requires serious gearage, so I want to add a 10-speed 42t cog in the rear.  I've seen lots of questions about 42t cogs with 1x, but what about a 2x?  I'm thinking a mountain bike derailer would do the trick, but I have also read that a longer B-screw and/or a drop down hanger would mean I wouldn't have to change derailers.  If the former, what mountain bike derailer would you suggest?  If the latter, what's the name of the hanger?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alberto Contador?  Just eat some "tainted beef".  I hear it makes you stronger, as if by magic.  ;-)